# Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for in weblogic starting

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

This problem occurs when the project is added to weblogic and it starts to appear. I have found similar problems but have not solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem that just change the jdk version of weblogic to the corresponding jdk version.
In myelipse open the Preferences and search 'weblogic10.x' choose the jdk and chenge the jdk version.